# Use a progressbar inside a custom view?

Tags: android, progress-bar, draw, android-custom-view

Hi i have made a custom view and a lifebarprocess.xml . I want to draw the lifebar in my custom view with all the other things i draw. But i don't know how to:

-Creat/reference the processbar inside my view and how i can draw it.
-May change the progressbar xml ?

The custom view (shorted):

```
public class Gamecontroller_View  extends View implements OnGestureListener{

private Paint mPaint;

public Gamecontroller_View(){
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.OUTER));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

  @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

      if (fingerpointer != null){
          mPaint.setColor(colors[0]);
          canvas.drawCircle(fingerpointer.x, fingerpointer.y, 30, mPaint);
          }

       //I want to draw a Progressbar's current appearance here

      }

}
```

lifeprocessbar.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="5dip" />
      <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
        android:centerY="0.5"
        android:endColor="#ff747674"
        android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
      <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
          <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#ff0000"
            android:startColor="#ff3300" />
      </shape>
    </clip>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

there is also the lifebarprocess_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/playerlifeprocessbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:progress="90"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/lifeprocessbar" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My someone can help - thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider extending [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) in your `Gamecontroller_View` instead of View. From the documentation:

> A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called
>   children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views
>   containers.